# Getting the difference from two arrays Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have this array of names and a main object I want to intersect the two, the common will be removed the and the rest will be retained.

VPC Names

```
["A_VPC", "B_VPC"]
```

ECS_OBJECTS

```
[{
"vpc_name": "A_VPC",
"client_name": "A"
},
{
"vpc_name": "B_VPC",
"client_name": "B"
},
{
"vpc_name": "C_VPC",
"client_name": "C"
}]
```

The end result I want will be that every common will be removed except C because they are not in common with the two objects.

```
[{
"vpc_name":"C_VPC",
"client_name": "C"
}]
```

My code thus far is some like this..

```
- name: Intersect ecs_instances objects to the existing VPC created
  set_fact:
    vpc_to_be_created: "{{ ecs_instances | difference(vpc_names) }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this the code that you're looking for ?

```
- set_fact:
    vpc_to_be_created: "{{ vpc_to_be_created | combine(item) }}"
  loop: "{{ ecs_objects }}"
  when: item.vpc_name not in vpc_names
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest and fastest way would be probably using JMESPath:

```
- name: Intersect ecs_instances objects to the existing VPC created
  set_fact:
    vpc_to_be_created: "{{ ecs_instances | json_query(query) }}"
  vars:
    query: "@[?!contains(`{{ vpc_names|to_json }}`, vpc_name)]"
```

---

Or build a differential list from scratch, as suggested in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52575118/2947502), but with fixed code:

```
- set_fact:
    vpc_to_be_created: "{{ vpc_to_be_created | default([]) + [item] }}"
  loop: "{{ ecs_instances }}"
  when: item.vpc_name not in vpc_names
```

<sup>This has a drawback of being less efficient (loop), a somewhat messy output because of that, and a requirement for the `set_fact` task (you can use the above JMESPath query directly in other modules).</sup>